# report lm regression with markdown R

Tags: r, markdown

I am using Markdown to report a code in R. When I run the code this work perfect in R. But when I use the Knit button say: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclosed) object urbrate don't found. If I delete the line

model2 <-lm(formula = urbrate ~ fpresence*d_1750 + fpresence*d_1800 + fpresence*d_1850 + fpresence*d_1875 + fpresence*d_1900 + d_Rhineland + d_Mark + d_WestphaliawithoutMark + d_BavarianPalatinate + d_Brunswick + d_Hanover + d_SaxonyProvince + d_PomeraniawithoutSwedishPomerania + d_Silesia + d_Wuerttemberg +d_Baden + d_BavariaOld + d_Saxony + d_Brandenburg + d$`d_Schleswig-Holstein` + d$`d_Hessen-Darmstadt,rightoftheRhine` + d$`d_Hessen-Kassel` + d_EastPrussia + d$`d_Mecklenburg-Schwerin` - fpresence -1,data=d1)

Then the code works. I had tried many forms to solve this but I can´t. My code is:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library("stargazer")
library("ggplot2")
library("lattice")
library("psych")
library("dummies")
options(warn=-1)


```

```{r cars}
mydata = read.csv("data.csv")


```


```{r qd}  

d1 <- mydata
d1 <- cbind(d, dummy(d$year, sep = "_"))    
d1 <- cbind(d, dummy(d$name, sep = "_"))   

```


```{r qf2}

model2 <-lm(formula = urbrate ~ fpresence*d_1750 + fpresence*d_1800 + fpresence*d_1850 + fpresence*d_1875 + fpresence*d_1900 + d_Rhineland + d_Mark + d_WestphaliawithoutMark + d_BavarianPalatinate + d_Brunswick + d_Hanover + d_SaxonyProvince + d_PomeraniawithoutSwedishPomerania + d_Silesia + d_Wuerttemberg +d_Baden + d_BavariaOld + d_Saxony + d_Brandenburg + d$`d_Schleswig-Holstein` + d$`d_Hessen-Darmstadt,rightoftheRhine` + d$`d_Hessen-Kassel` + d_EastPrussia + d$`d_Mecklenburg-Schwerin` - fpresence -1,data=d1)


summary(model2)
nobs(model2)
```
````

Thanks!!

Comment: `d1 <- cbind(d, dummy(d$year, sep = "_"))` what is `d` here?

Comment: Can you dput(head(d1)) just before doing the lm?

Comment: It doesnt know ubrate. Do a glimpse d1 in the qf2 chunk to check. It might be you need to call the original data inside the same r chunck or set a persistent option for knitr so that it can carry data from chunk to chunk (?)